# Android application is consuming high storage memory

Tags: android, asynchronous, memory, realm

[image]It's about a Memory consumption issue that I am facing with my application.

The application basically uploads medias to a server.

i am using external libraries like **Realm, retrofit, Glide, sliding panel etc.**

**Is the library has anything to do with this issue ?**

**How to track the code that causes this issue?**

My **/data/data** folder takes only 833k size
[image]
Thank you

Comment: I'd look at what files are in your private directory and figure out what they all are.  Of course I'd be more worried about using 8 GB of data today.

Comment: actually, I uploaded 8gb of data. the only thing I am saving is a log file which is around 1 MB

Comment: What Gabe Sechan said. App files are saved under `/data/data/<package_name>`, so I would start there. From the info given so far, it is impossible to tell what might be causing it.

Comment: Check the data folder and you'll see what is 182 MBs of stuff

Comment: my /data/data folder takes only 833kb size

Comment: check out the image of my data/data folder

Comment: Then your application is just generally big, what is the APK size?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's below 20MB

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Issue is fixed...Realm caused trouble. Realm.close() solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realm was the cause of the trouble. **Realm.close()** solved my problem.

```
 realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm {
                    if (!realm.isClosed()){
                        Realm realm1 = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm1.close();
                    }
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving your Media inside the application folder, this could happen. For example, you must be hiding your data within the application and no other application or user can access it unless they are using rooted devices.

The library you mentioned could affect the size of the application but its very minor. Not like you are having it right now.